# Library not found for -lBugsnagReactNative when running on physical device

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, bugsnag

```
ld: library not found for -lBugsnagReactNative
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
```

To Reproduce:
If you're running a React Native app on a physical device, the official docs tell you to run it on Xcode (arrow button in the IDE).  If you run it there, you get the error above/below:

[image: Screenshot]

Steps taken to try and fix the issue:

1) `pod install` in ios directory,

2) Make sure Bugsnag is installed, with the correct version

3) Delete contents of build folder

4) Terminate metro bundler packager

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, it was better to run on a physical device using the command line on my terminal.  I used:

`npm run ios -- --device "my device"`

And had to install `ios-deploy` beforehand to get it to work:

`npm install -g ios-deploy`